# What are the top 'mistakes' a developer can make that can cause a Database server to crash?

Tags: database

I'd like to know the most common mistakes a developer can make that may cause a Database Server to crash and/or become unresponsive and/or abort.

I've had this problem some times now and I'd like to know what are some common mistakes that(mostly unexperienced) developers who write the queries and the scripts that access the database server can run into.

I'm not really looking at things from a DBA's perspective, am rather hoping I can have a simple list with perhaps some 'good practices' for developers who have to work with databases on a daily basis (like me).

Comment: Why close? Is this not a good question? I did say I'm looking at things from a developer's perspective, not a DBA's, that's why I thought people here from SO could profit from my question. I'm not a DBA, I'm a programmer who has to write queries as part of his daily routine.

Comment: People who frequent dba.SE have a lot of experience on things that Developers do that cause Databases to become unresponsive. This isn't really doesn't fall into what the FAQ describes as "practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page."

Comment: I agree with Felipe. This is a valuable question from the point of view of a developer that is trying to avoid being yelled at by the database administrator.

Comment: I think it's sufficiently developer-focused to *not* close

Comment: Actually in hindsight it will probably be closed on dba.SE as well. Pretty much any thing that's got the words "What are the top..." will be closed on many of the SE sites

Comment: Read and "digest" http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/04/video-mistakes-that-wont-scale/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main reason I see crashes / hangs, in order from most frequent to least frequent:

1. A frequently used query having a ludicrous number of JOINs, or returning a massive amount of data.
2. Very IO intensive queries, such as a `LOAD DATA INFILE` on MySQL.
3. Heavy use of table locks that cause a massive backlog.
4. Machine ran out of memory and the DBMS process was killed to prevent the whole box crashing.
5. Some client code spazzing out and flooding the DBMS with too many connections, causing legitimate client connections to time out.
6. The DBMS crashing due to a bug. Rare, but annoying to track down.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be very worried indeed if a developer could force a database server to crash. I would expect the server to be sufficiently robust to withstand such abuse!

However developers can commonly cause a degree of grief through two particular actions:

1. writing queries that return huge amounts of data. This often occurs when the developer chooses to grab all available data and then perform filtering/sorting etc. on the client side (by client, I mean the client of the db). For this reason (amongst others) it's a good idea to get DBAs to review interactions with the database and to suggest efficient querying practises, SQL etc. to avoid this.
2. consuming all available database connections. This often occurs when database connections are not closed upon completion, and can often be alleviated through the use of db frameworks (e.g. from a Java perspective, Spring-JDBC)

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed if transactions are committed or rolled back approriately, can cause the system to be unresponsive. However I think this doesnt effect the whole server if only one or two transactions havent been committed.

However I can imagine if alot was happening, it might overload it. But thats just my opinion from a developers view.

Comment: -1 for vague answer. "Too much stuff happening" isn't specific enough to be useful for anyone trying to track down a problem.